# AWS Change Stream Logs Does Not Clear After Log Retention Period, Instead Clear When Size Exceed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, changestream

We are having an application highly depend on document db change streams. We have set change_stream_log_retention_duration to 7 days but instead, it collects logs till maximum log size reaches. This is also mentioned in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/change_streams.html) but the product it self designed for MongoDB and later we had to use documentDB for a specific client.

Once the log reaches mentioned log size, change stream enabled collections are getting a locked by a collection lock and unfortunately it is locked for 1h. This impacts the usage of application.

1. Any one else experiencing same issue with change streams?
2. Any possible way to clean the logs before reaching it to it's maximum size?

Comment: `Any possible way to clean the logs before reaching it to it's maximum size` it is a stream, it is not be manually removed or manipulated. `collections are getting a locked` I sugges you reach aws dev forum or support for this